# Search nodes in network using akka.

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

Is there a way to search nodes in network so that if any node down we can reconnect it again when it becomes up. Currently I am using mdns but I want to achieve this with akka. I am using akka with java.

Comment: As far as I remember, node should reconnect automatically if it's a member of Akka cluster.

Comment: It try to reconnect for some time but after some moment a termination request will arrive for specific unreachable node.

Answer (score 1):

You may use 2 approaches here:

1) **External** - run an instance of [consul.io](https://www.consul.io/) along with the cluster. By reading the status of the **consul** cluster you will know all the machines connected to the cluster - that will give you some idea about the total set of the nodes and their IP addresses. Now use `JMX` anywhere to retrieve the status of the Akka cluster - you're looking for `akka:type=Cluster` bean here and it's property `Members` or `ClusterStatus`. Those will return you the cluster status - hence you will know the set of nodes available in the **akka** cluster. If you subtract the set of the nodes in **Akka** cluster from the nodes in the **consul** cluster - you will get those that were removed/quarantined by the Akka cluster quorum, and most likely those has to be restarted.

2) **Internal** - once I have [added](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/19107) the `ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent` to the Akka remoting. This event is fired when a node is `removed` from the cluster, and then is put in quarantine - so it can't reconnect to the cluster automatically.  So you can create something like this:

```
  object ClusterWatcher {

    private class DefaultClusterWatcher extends Actor with ClusterWatcher {
      override def receive = handleQuarantinedRestart
    }

    def registerRestartJVMWatcherActor(sys: ActorSystem) = {
      val ref = sys.actorOf(Props[DefaultClusterWatcher])
      sys.eventStream.subscribe(ref, classOf[ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent])
    }

  }

  trait ClusterWatcher {

    _: Actor ⇒

    def handleQuarantinedRestart: Actor.Receive = {
      case err: ThisActorSystemQuarantinedEvent ⇒
        import SlackNotification._
        slackEmergency(s"Actor system ${err.localAddress} is quarantined by ${err.remoteAddress}, restarting")
        sys.exit(1)
    }

  }
```

and use it after you've created the actor system:

```
val sys = ActorSystem("MyCluster", config)
ClusterWatcher.registerRestartJVMWatcherActor(sys)
```

Then, whenever the `DefaultClusterWatcher` will receive the quarantine event - it will restart the entire JVM (or do something else about the actor system - up to you).

I find the combination of those methods to be most robust - in my setup it allows me to run self-sustained distributed cluster of 30 nodes in different data centers with modest network connection.